# How to use graphs to determine if a function is surjective or bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, graphing-functions

I know that you can determine if a function is injective by using the horizontal line test, but is there a similar approach to find out if a function is surjective or bijective? Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the difficulty is that one can hardly look at the entire, infinite, graph.  That said, "injective" means no horizontal line intersects the graph more than once and "surjective" means that every horizontal line intersects the graph at least once.

Comment: Also a horizontal line test.

Comment: First, you need to know if your function is continuous, or exactly where it is discontinuous. If you have a function which is continuous on some interval, then it passes through everything between its lowest and highest values on that interval.